# How to output info about performed test in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I have set up multiple tests for my laravel api, but when I run the unit-test, all I get is:

```
~api$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/v1/
Time: 171 ms, Memory: 8.00MB
OK (3 test, 4 assertion)
```

I would like to get an output similar to command's `info` method (maybe even progress bar if the tests execution start to take long period of time):

```
$this->output->info('Starting data fetch ...');
```

so that I can see, what tests are performed. The desired result would be:

```
~api$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/v1/
Running PassportTest
Running DescribeTest
Running UserListTest

Time: 171 ms, Memory: 8.00MB
OK (3 test, 4 assertion)
```

What is the correct way to do this for each test I've created?

*Edit: So far I managed something similair to it with Dumper:*

```
(new Dumper())->dump('PassportTest');
```

*This gives me a quoted text:*

```
"PassportTest"
```

Comment: What version of phpunit are you running? I'm running 5.7.21 and I get `.` for every succeeded test (or `f` or `e` for failures and errors) while the tests are running.

Comment: Yes, I also get the dots with PHPUnit 5.7.21, I was talking about more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **`--debug`** flag:

```
~api$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/v1/ --debug
```

------ output ------

```
Starting test 'Class::yourTestMethod'.
. //(Result like: ., E, F, etc)

Starting test 'Class::otherTestMethod'.
F //(Result like: ., E, F, etc)
```

I usually add two more flags to help me in the analysis:

`--log-json`: to output the log files to json

`--tap`: to generate a test summary file (execution times and results)

**See the docs:** https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. I knew that there should be a simple and clean solution to this.